# Sort values that contain letters and symbols in a custom order

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Can you change the MySQL sort by function? I am trying to sort my values according to an arbitrary order.

Currently looking for ways to inject a function that might help me out here short of adding a column and modifying the import.

This is the order I want:

```
AAA
AA+
AA
AA-
A+
A
A-
BBB+
BBB
BBB-
BB+
BB
BB-
B+
B
B-
CCC+
CCC
CCC-
CC
```

This is my result using sort by:

```
A
A+
A-
AA
AA+
AA-
AAA
B
B+
B-
BB
BB+
BB-
BBB
BBB+
BBB-
C
CC
CCC
CCC+
CCC-
```

EDIT:
Attempting but getting syntax errors:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sortRating (s CHAR(20))
RETURNS INT(2)
DECLARE var INT
CASE s
    WHEN 'AAA' THEN SET var = 1
    WHEN 'AA+' THEN SET var = 2
    ELSE
        SET VAR = 3
END CASE
RETURN var
END;
```

Comment: You have only alphabets at the start of the string ?

Comment: Is the set of values finite? If so, it would be easiest to create a lookup table with assigned rank values.

Comment: yes—set of values is finite. was just looking into writing my first stored procedure with a whole bunch of case statements. @MichaelBerkowski - what do you mean by a lookup table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using the following syntax:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(<field_name>, comma-separated-custom-order)
```

for instance, if the expression you want to order by is called `rating`, then your `ORDER BY` clause would read:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(rating, 'AAA', 'AA+', 'AA', 'AA-', 'A+', 'A', 'A-', 
                       'BBB+', 'BBB', 'BBB-', 'BB+', 'BB', 'BB-', 
                       'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'CCC+', 'CCC', 'CCC-', 'CC')
```

Here's documentation on the [FIELD FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Comment: this function is great! now i only need to append this string to a zf2 query. :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a pattern here:

```
BBB+
BBB
BBB-
BB+
BB
BB-
B+
B
B-
```

Think of each character as a column and sort each column in this order:

1. Letters
2. `+`
3. empty string
4. `-`

```sql
SELECT rating
FROM test
ORDER BY
         MID(rating, 1, 1),
    CASE MID(rating, 2, 1) WHEN '+' THEN 2 WHEN '' THEN 3 WHEN '-' THEN 4 ELSE 1 END, 
    CASE MID(rating, 3, 1) WHEN '+' THEN 2 WHEN '' THEN 3 WHEN '-' THEN 4 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE MID(rating, 4, 1) WHEN '+' THEN 2 WHEN '' THEN 3 WHEN '-' THEN 4 ELSE 1 END
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ae254/1)

Comment: interesting! thanks! other function was easier but this is pretty great and instructive